# Azure Event Hub gone offline

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

Our azure event hub has been running for a few months now in a production environment. Today the event hub stopped receiving inputs and processing any outputs. Not sure what the problem is?

[image]

Our stream analytics also can't connect to the event hub anymore - also one of the stream jobs has a status of 'degraded'. Could this be the cause for the whole hub to go down?

[image]

Comment: Have you contacted Azure support already?

Comment: Yes I did - they suggested I post it here and they will have a look at it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the degraded status of your Stream Analytics job is caused by the Event Hub access issue. You can confirm this from the job's activity log.